# I need help to identify a technology i only can define as "magnetic data pins"

Tags: components, identification, data

I was interested in the "wireless" pins technology used on this here:
[image: roli blocks(music)]

Would be much appreciated if you could guide me towards some modules/components or the name of such tech. Or something similar for future projects.

Also, it would be helful with some tips as to finding components in the future when I don't know the names of them.

Thanks.

EDIT 1:
[Component website](https://roli.com/products/blocks)

Comment: is there a website for that device?

Comment: found it ... http://next-startup.com/the-building-blocks-of-electronic-music/

Comment: https://roli.com/products/blocks

Comment: Huh? Without explaining what this thing does or even what purpose it has, this is a non-question.  I might be willing to follow a link for more details, but the basic information needs to be here in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used these, but I believe the units are held together with magnets and little spring-loaded contacts touch when the units are brought together, allowing those contacts to transmit data.

It's not a standard. It's just a clever mechanical way of wiring things together.

See [Apple MagSafe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MagSafe) and [Snap Jacks cable](https://www.musiciansfriend.com/accessories/snap-jack-instrument-cable). It's all proprietary connectors, but the magnets are separate from the data/signal/power transmission.

Comment: I think that the explanation of @schadjo is correct. Looking at the picture the [pogo pins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogo_pin) came to my mind.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. You're surely more helpful than the "pros/veterans".